# How require braces on if statements with CheckStyle?

Tags: java, checkstyle

The following XML allows the below code. But I want to require braces on all `if` statements.

```
<module name="NeedBraces">
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE" />
</module>
```

Allows this:

```
if ( x == 3 )
    doIt();
```

I want that to be an error and instead require this:

```
if ( x == 3 ) {
    doIt();
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: According to [the docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html#NeedBraces), your configuration is correct. Are you sure that you didn't accidentally set `allowSingleLineStatement` to `true`? Maybe try setting it to `false` explicitly.

Comment: Your configuration is indeed correct with all versions I tested up to 3.
Please make sure you don't have a severity of `ignore` set somewhere and that you are giving Checkstyle the correct configuration with the XML you pasted above.

Comment: @ThomasJensen Yes, I checked and `allowSingleLineStatement` is not anywhere in the style.xml. Is that a default?

Comment: @rveach The only ignore I have is on `LineLength` where I have an ignore pattern for comments.

Comment: Than please provide us more information like your entire configuration and snippets of how you are calling Checkstyle with it. Nothing is showing your problem as it should be working from what I am seeing.

Comment: @rveach It's google's check style XML other than the change I'm trying to make. https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Comment: I also asked how you are running it. Maven? Are you specifying your local config and not the one embedded in the JAR? If you want help, I need to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @rveach Sorry, I missed that. I'm running it via the IntelliJ plugin.